# How to extract a float from a string

Tags: python, string

I have a string: `string = "2017.5 is halfway through the year"`. Is there a way to extract this `"2017.5"` from the string? I tried using `string.isdigit()`, but that only worked for non-floats.

Comment: float(string.split(' ')[0])

Comment: `string.split()[0]`

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int

Answer (score 2):

If your float is always expressed in decimal notation something like

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("\d+\.\d+", "2017.5 is halfway through the year")
['2017.5']
```

may suffice.

For parse int and float (point separator) values:

```
re.findall( r'\d+\.*\d*', '2017.5 is halfway through the year' )
```

result:

```
['2017.5']
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an example using `re.match`:

```
>>> import re
>>> ok = '2017.5 and some stuff'
>>> hmm = re.match(r'[0-9\.]+', ok)
>>> hmm.group()
'2017.5'
```

`r'[0-9\.]+'` is a regex to extract the group that matches numbers and periods

Answer (score 0):

just a dirty implementation without regex and with the single digit/float per sentence:

```
s = "new 2017.5 is halfway through the year1"

def process(all,new):

    def is_float_try(str):
        try:
            float(str)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

    return new if new.isdigit() or is_float_try(new) else all

print reduce(process,s.split(),'')
# 2017.5
```